# Sublime Text: select the object containing the insertion point?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'd like to select an object around the insertion point/cursor in Sublime Text,

eg, given:

```
{
    'foo':'bar',
    'baz':{
        'zoo|':'zam' <- Note insertion point here
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to highlight the object around the insertion point, in this case:

- The string 'zoo'
- The hashmap containing that string
- The parent hashmap

Depending on how many times I repeat the key combo / mouse action.

Is there a way to do this, either built into sublime or with an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Selection menu. Specifically, the Expand to Scope option. I know there us a key command for it (ctrl+shift+space in Windows/Linux, Shift+Command+Space in OS X)